# Is there a Management Service (WMSVC) UI in IIS 7 on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, user-interface, service, iis-7, remote-server

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate x86 and IIS 7 on the same machine. I want to "web deploy" a silverlight application to this IIS 7 with VS 2010.

I know, that I need to configure the Management Service (WMSVC) and the Web Deployment Service (MsDepSvc), so that the web deployment task in VS 2010 will work.

Looking into my IIS 7 Management UI (inetmgr.exe), I can't find the entry "Management Service" to do this.

I could find many tutorials to do this, but all are talking about Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.

So my 2 question are:

1.) Is there any way, to activate the "Management Service" UI entry in the IIS 7 UI?

2.) If not, are there any alternate tools with a UI to do this?

If it is not clear, what I am talking about - here is a link to a tutorial, where the UI entry "Management Service" is shown in IIS 7:

[iis-7-remote-administration](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/iis-7-remote-administration)

Thank you for your comments.

**I just found out, that this problem is beeing discussed also here:**

[Missing Management Service Delegation icon](http://forums.iis.net/p/1171432/1956059.aspx)

I tried the suggested solutions (custom install of web deploy, the script), but nothing worked.

Am I missing a point. There must be a bug in the msi for web deployment 3.0.

Comment: Web Deploy works fine on my Windows 7 on which I installed Web Deploy 3.5.  IIS does not show Management Service, however Web Management Service is running in the background. I have to confess how Web Deploy works on Windows 7 is still a bit of mystery to me. Anyway, it works flawlessly.  I use VS2012 to deploy web applications on the the Windows 7 machine via Web Deploy.

Comment: On Windows Server 2012, there's a registry key called HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server -> EnableRemoteManagement. If you can find it in Windows 7, trying setting that to 1. When I did that and restarted the Web Management service, the icons appeared in the IIS Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know why, but after all, the VS 2010 build in method "Web Deploy" didn't **not** work for me. I just gave up and wrote my own deploy batch script, that builds my application and copies all the relevant data to the IIS.

I want to publish this batch script here for everybody having the same problem. There are some things to keep in mind before using this script:

**1.)** Set Local Copy = True to all your referenced DLLs in Silverlight Web Project.

**2.)** Every WCF RIA Service needs a separate *.svc file. The svc file needs to include the complete service namespace+name and also the factory class, which is used to instance the service. The content of the file could look like this:

```
<%@ServiceHost language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Fullnamespace.Servicename" Factory="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory"%>
```

I my case all my svc files are in zhe ClientBin Folder. Keep in mind that you have to write them on your own and set Locaol Copy = True. Also keep in mind, that you have to invoke the correct svc file in your SL Client.

That could look like this:

```
LoginContext _loginContext = new LoginContext(Globals.URI.getServiceUri("http://yourdomain/ClientBin/YourService.svc"));
LoadOperation<ServiceLog> _loadOperation = _loginContext.Load<ServiceLog>(_loginContext.LogInQuery(user.EMail, user.Passwort), LoginCallBack, true);
```

**3.** The following batch script builds your application. Then it copies the files to your IIS. For debugging issues the pdb files are included in the xap files. KEEP IN MIND that all the paths in the batch relate to my system. You will certainly have to change them. Maybe you take this as an inspiration to build you own script.

**PLEASE BE VERY CAREFUL WITH THIS SCRIPT AND DON'T USE IT IF YOUR ARE NOT FAMILIAR WITH BATCH LANGUAGE. IT WILL DELETE AND CREATE FOLDERS ON YOUR HARDDRIVE. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**

```
SET DestPath=D:\Sources Internet\www.MyDomain.de\%2
SET DevelopmentPath=D:\Sources\MyDomain\MyDomain.Web\%3

RD /S /Q "%DestPath%" 

MKDIR "%DestPath%"

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" "D:\Sources\MyDomain\MyDomain\MyDomain.sln" /p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package;_PackageTempDir="D:\Sources Internet\www.MyDomain.de"

DEL "%DestPath%\Web.config" /s /q

COPY "%DevelopmentPath%\Web.config" "%DestPath%\Web.config"

COPY "D:\Sources\MyDomain\MyDomain\Bin\Debug\MyDomain.pdb" "D:\Sources Internet\www.MyDomain.de\ClientBin\MyDomain.pdb"

CD /D D:\Sources Internet\www.MyDomain.de\ClientBin

REN *.xap *.rar

SET WINRAR="C:\Program Files\WinRAR"

%WINRAR%\WinRAR.exe a MyDomain MyDomain.pdb 

DEL MyDomain.pdb

REN *.rar *.xap

COPY "D:\Sources Internet\www.MyDomain.de\ClientBin\MyDomain.xap" "D:\Sources Internet\www.MyDomain.de\bin\MyDomain.xap"
```

**PLEASE BE VERY CAREFUL WITH THIS SCRIPT AND DON'T USE IT IF YOUR ARE NOT FAMILIAR WITH BATCH LANGUAGE. IT WILL DELETE AND CREATE FOLDERS ON YOUR HARDDRIVE. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**

Using this method I don't need the VS 2010 web deploy anymore and I also can run and debug my SL application on IIS 7.5.